# switch between projects while debugging in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have two projects A and B both are built differently, but the jars from project B are copied to project A before it builds.
Now I got to debug through project A and place a breakpoint in B's source code and debug through code of B instead of  its jar in buildpath .

Is there any way to do that?

I had tried to link B's source folder to A, but when I place a breakpoint in B's code the debugger goes to same location in its jar.

Comment: I do not understand where is the problem - breakpoint works, you can see the source, what else you need? Do you want project A and B to be built separately?

Comment: breakpoint works ..in jar it goes to .class file where I am not able to view or inspect values of variables. ...and yes the projects need to be separately built

Comment: it's working fine for me, are you building the jar with Eclipse ?

Comment: no, the jar is being built from ant build which may be run from eclipse

Comment: there is `-g` flag (Generate all debugging info) for `javac`, try this ;-) you can split targets to production and development if you do not want this in production, but at least for some time I recommend debug information in your code, it's good to know line number when exception occurs ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you have to add project B as reference to the build path instead of the jar of project B.

But it also works to set a breakpoint in the code of the jar file. For doing this you just have to attach the sources to the code once.